# Robust way to close multiple tabs/windows, by their title, in Chrome using AppleScript?

Tags: loops, google-chrome, indexing, applescript

I want to close all tabs in Chrome that have a specific title using AppleScript. I came up with this code but it doesn't feel robust:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set tabsToClose to {}
    repeat with win in windows
        repeat with t in tabs of win
            set tabTitle to title of t
            if tabTitle is "New tab" then
                set end of tabsToClose to t
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat

    repeat with tabToClose in reverse of tabsToClose
        close tabToClose
    end repeat
end tell
```

Both `index` and `id` of tabs and windows changes if you close an "earlier" tab/window. If you have one window with four tabs and you want to close the tabs with index two and three, after you closed tab two, tab three is renumbered to two (and if you now do "close tab three" you actually close the fourth tab, which shouldn't be closed).

My way around this was to loop through the list of tabs to close in reverse, but that feels like a hack that is prone to break. Are there better ways?

Comment: You just don't need to add an extra layer of complexity (create a list tabsToClose). Why not close tabs right away?

Comment: @RobertKniazidis Because of the reasons I described in my question. When you "get all windows/tabs" you get an index of each. That index changes when you close a tab/window. If you have 5 tabs and loop over them and in the loop close one of them, you will get an out of bounds error when you reach number 5.

Comment: Are you sure that the `id` changes?

Comment: @Mockman Yes,  I am sure.

Comment: Weird. I tried it with opera (which is chrome under the hood) and the IDs persist. The one peculiarity is that they don't necessarily go in order, seemingly because tabs aren't created left to right. It's unusual that chrome would be the only app that arbitrarily changes IDs.

Comment: Actually, it's strange that, as you say, the IDs of the remaining tabs change with the destruction of the "New tab" tabs. Are you sure you're not confusing **IDs** with tab **Indexes** (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...etc)? Normally, the indexes should change, and the IDs should remain the same for the lifetime of the tabs. If the IDs change, then this is an obvious application bug and it becomes impossible to keep track of the remaining tabs.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis Didn't keep the code sample which was broken so I can't reproduce it :-(

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with win in windows
        close (tabs of win whose title is "New tab")
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: I was also able to have it recognize tabs by URL instead of by title.  The URL displayed in the Chrome address bar was missing `http://` on the front and `/` on the end, both of which Applescript needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the repeat loop.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    close (tabs of windows whose title is "New tab")
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This single line is the best way to do this

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to close (tabs of windows whose title is "New tab")
```

… and when you remove items from a list, always do it backwards, using "reverse". This wont change the order of remaining items in the list :

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with thisWindow in windows
        set tabList to tabs of thisWindow
        repeat with thisTab in the reverse of tabList
            if title of thisTab is "New tab" then close thisTab
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

I hope this will help you …